# How can I listen a message queue in flask microservices

Tags: python, flask, microservices, pika

Here is my flask microservices scenario.

[image]

`Activity-server` expose a api for ticket purchasing.
`A-server` will push a message with `order_id(no)` to rabbitmq after payment completion.
And `C-server` insert `order_no` to mysql since it received the specific message.

My solution is just start a pika thread and it seems works.

```
# content of /user/src/app.py
def create_app(config=None):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    t = Thread(target=start_message_consumer)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()

    return app

def start_message_consumer():
    credential = pika.credentials.PlainCredentials(xxxxx)
    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(xxx, credentials=credential))
    channel = connection.channel()

    channel.queue_declare(queue='order')

    def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
        ....Insert statement

    channel.basic_consume(callback, queue='order', no_ack=True)
    channel.start_consuming()
```

> Do I need locks somewhere Or is there a better approach (like flask extension)to achieve this?

Comment: Have you came up with a good implementation ? ... I'm struggling with the same thing.

Comment: @sptremblay Yea, just start a new python process to handle messages, and if you need interact with flask just `from main import app` import flask instance.